# Date Of Birth Validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a date of birth like 12-08-1989 in text box in HTML.I want to validate that the user must be of 18 years old in javascript.

I have used Date function in javascript but it seems like it accept YYYY-MM-DD format but i want to validate in DD-MM-YYYY.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What if JavaScript is disabled in browser?

Comment: That might be a possibility.But I need it can you please tell me how can i do it in javascript

Comment: I don't know @BalusC, is that still a question in the era of Facebook, Google, etc. with massive jQuery/AJAX-based UIs?

Comment: @benqus: On purpose, just to workaround "the silly validation" :) By the way relatively a lot mobile browsers have it disabled and the mobile market should not be underestimated.

Comment: You can set the format for dates in javascript. Refer `http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format`

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, definately, I agree with that but still... Users want all-shiny and interactive stuff (probably wihtout freakin' flash =D ) so they should allow JavaScript, right?

Comment: @BalusC - So what if JavaScript is disabled? You should _always_ validate server-side, but that doesn't mean it's a bad plan to also do some validation in JS as well...

Comment: I think both client-side and server-side validations need be included.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Exactly. Don't forget to validate on the server side as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
var pattern =/^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$/;
if(pattern.test(str_input_date))
{
     alert("valid date");
}
```

This should give you a start. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using some validation framework, like [jQuery.validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). This is by far more consistent way to handle validation in your code. If this is the only validated field in your app, you can, of course, use naive implementation as provided above.

Whether you need some advanced date validation rules, you could use a JS date framework, like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) (or [Date.js](http://datejs.com), which is pretty outdated at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the date class, just like this

```
try{
    var x=new Date('1/1/2001');
    var Cnow=new Date();//current Date
    if(Cnow.getFullYear()- x.getFullYear()<18){
    alert('not old enough');
    }
    else{
      //success !!!
    }

}
catch(ejs){alert('invalid')}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but seems like it does not work for 01-01-2001 format

Comment: there is a typo in the "Cnow.getFullYesr" i wrote yesr instead of yeAr... and this format is working properly

Comment: But this doesn't test if the person is more than 18 years old, it tests if the year of their birth was at least 18 years before the current year.

Comment: this is a very simple test, i showed the way you can easily extend the method to validate more things ...

Answer (score 0):

*"I have used Date function in javascript but it seems like it accept YYYY-MM-DD format but i want to validate in DD-MM-YYYY"*

You can create a Date object by passing the year, month and day (and, optionally, the hour, minute, second, and millisecond) values separately:

```
var aDate = new Date(2012, 5, 22);
```

So if you use a regex or other string methods to extract the pieces from what the user entered then you can create a date from DD-MM-YYYY (or whatever other) format you like.

The way I'd test if the user is at least 18 years old would be to add 18 years to their date of birth and see if that is on or before today's date:

```
aDate.setFullYear( aDate.getFullYear() + 18 )
```

The various methods available on a Date object are [listed at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods).